# Checking if fields are all filled in PHP

Tags: php, css, for-loop

I've made a page where you can set the number of rows of information you want to give in, this data goes through a function and let the number of rows appear. Now each of this information has to be sent through but first I want to check if all fields are filled in.

Generating the rows I have used a for-loop.

This is what I try to do now:

```
<td <?php checkfilled("datum".$x) ?> ><input size="6" type='text' name='datum<?php echo $x ?>' value='<?php setvalue2("datum".$x)?>' /></td>
```

The function checkfilled will try and check whether it's filled in or not.

```
function checkfilled($fieldname){

    if(isset($_POST['send'])){
        if($_POST[$fieldname]=="" || !isset($_POST[$fieldname])){       
            echo 'class="error"';
        }else{
            echo "";
        }
    }

}
```

The error class contains that the background-color will be set to green if it's not filled in.

But for somewhat odd reason it doesn't work.

Does anyone know what might be wrong and how to solve this?

Comment: Are you expecting this on page load? Or after submitting the page?

Comment: After clicking the submit button at the bottom of the form, yes.

Comment: Can you `var_dump($_POST[$fieldname]);` before the `if`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine. I ran some tests and the problem was with styling the `<td>` tag. You didn't specify, but I am wondering if your `<td>` is wrapped with `<table><tr>`. If not, that is the problem.

I tested your exact code, it failed as you described. Then I changed the `<td>` to a `<div>` and it worked like a charm.

Then I wrapped the `<td>` in a `<table><tr>` ... `</tr></table>` and it also worked fine.

So, ensure that your `<td>` is in a row, in a table, and your code should work.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
function checkfilled($fieldname){

if(isset($_POST['send'])){
    if(isset($_POST[$fieldname]) && !empty($_POST[$fieldname])){       
        echo 'class="success"';
    }else{
        echo 'class="error"';
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Wrong as that would produce `<td success>` || `<td error>`, not applying the class with styling.

Comment: well that was an example. You can always change what will be echoed. change it to echo 'class="error"' on else part and similarly success on if part

Comment: That answer is better :)

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer but unfortunately it isn't working after changing the code. Any direction for what may be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(empty($_POST['fieldname'])){
echo "<div style="background:green;.....">This field is missing</div>";
}

else if(empty($_POST['another_field_name'])){
echo "<div style="background:green;.....">This field is missing</div>";
}
else{
echo "everything seems good, Let's do some math.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$_POST[$fieldname]=="" || !isset($_POST[$fieldname])
```

To:

```
empty($_POST[$fieldname])
```